# Eigenvalues of a matrix with negative entries

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am currently working on a problem involving the spectrum of a matrix which has negative entries.

More specifically, let $A$ be a matrix with entries negative entries $A_{ij}$. What conditions do we have to set on the $A_{ij}$ such that $A$ has *only* negative eigenvalues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem See if this may help you.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thanks, I'll check it out!

Comment: Do you have any other ideas in mind? I am not sure this helps since I can only find a bound on the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't any ideas. The only theory I know that deals with these things is the theorem of Perron-Frobenius and related things (irreducible matrices, etc...), so that's the place where I would search. But I cannot be more precise than that.